# Successful response only for entity class fields

Tags: java, spring-boot

Here is my entity class

```
public class Tran{

   @Id
   @NotNull
   @Column(unique = true)
   private String tranId;

   private String code;

   private String failureReason;

   @NotNull
   private Date transaDate;

   private String switchingId
}
```

This is my controller class

```
public class TranController{
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
    @PostMapping(value = "/pur", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String,Object>> createTran(@RequestHeader(required = false,name="request-id") String requestId,
                                                @RequestHeader(required = false,name="datetime") String requestDate,
                                                @RequestHeader(required = false,name= "channel") String requestChannel,
                                                @RequestBody TransRequestEntity createTransactionRequest,
                                                HttpServletRequest req) throws ApiBaseException {



        Tran tran = objectMapper.convertValue(createTranRequest,Trans.class);

        TransCreateResponseEntity tranCreateResponseEntity = tranCreateService.createTransaction(tran,requestId);

        Map<String,Object> trResponse = responseEntityTransformer.transform(transactionCreateResponseEntity,transCreateResponseTransformer);

        switch (transactionCreateResponseEntity.getTransactionResponseHeader().getResponseCode()){
            case "00" :
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(trResponse);
            case "10" : return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(trResponse);
            default: return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(trResponse);
        }
    }
}
```

I send this type json

```
{
  "tranId": "120",
  "code": "50ac",
  "transaDate": "2020/02/20",
  "switchingId": "464vc",
}
```

This request show the success response. there are no problem
But i send request like that

```
{
  "tranId": "120",
  "code": "50ac",
  "transaDate": "2020/02/20",
  "switchingId": "464vc",
  "xyz" : "test"
}
```

this is also show successful response, but i don't need xyz field, this field also not in the my entity class..
I want to show error massage like "bad request"  if I add another field that is not in the entity class

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring uses the Jackson library. By default, the `ObjectMapper` used by the framework sets its `FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES` to `false`.

Put this in your `application.properties`:

`spring.jackson.deserialization.fail-on-unknown-properties=true`

It will start failing for unrecognized properties. If you wish to handle the exception yourself, you can do so with

```java
@ExceptionHandler(UnrecognizedPropertyException.class)
```

More [here](https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring)